# Losing line breaks when doing a basic MySQL insert

Tags: mysql, insert, line-breaks

I have a simple MySQL query that takes an html string and inserts this into a database however I always lose the line breaks - do I need to do something for it to retain the line breaks in the insert query?

Comment: Are you sure they're really gone? If you're viewing your changes through a web based GUI you won't see the line breaks.

Comment: What @JohnConde said. Best way to test is to fetch it back.

Comment: What platform/language/framework are you using to get the string out of HTML and into MySQL? Is there something that parses out the string and runs the query? PHP? Perl? If there is an intermediary, it is likely that is where the data is being reformatted to remove newlines. If you are putting any string directly into MySQL with the CLI or equivalent, you can be sure that it isn't being reformatted.

Comment: cheers guy will try that now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the strings back in with a query, they see if they contain line breaks. It may also be a good idea to check for ascii 13, 10, and a combination of both. If it's going in with a linefeed character (10), it's possible that MySQL is expecting a carriage return/linefeed combination, or vice versa.

Comment: Line breaks are definately being removed - its appears in the DB before save with line break spacing - after the save it appears on a 'single line' - is there a reason for this?

Comment: Sometimes it will appear as a single line if the application expects a carriage-return linefeed combination but only gets a carriage return. To eliminate this possibility, look at the string contents character by character to see what's really there.